# How to determine callee function name in a script

Tags: bash, shell-script, function

To make it short, doing something like:

```
-bash$ function tt
{
 echo $0;
}

-bash$ tt
```

`$0` will return `-bash`, but how to get the function name called, i.e. `tt` in this example instead?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In `bash`, use [FUNCNAME](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-FUNCNAME) array:

```
tt() {
  printf '%s\n' "$FUNCNAME"
}
```

---

With some `ksh` implementations:

```
tt() { printf '%s\n' "$0"; }
```

In `ksh93`:

```
tt() { printf '%s\n' "${.sh.fun}"; }
```

From `ksh93d` and above, you can also use `$0` inside function to get the function name, but you must define function using `function name { ...; }` form.

---

In `zsh`, you can use `funcstack` array:

```
tt() { print -rl -- $funcstack[1]; }
```

or `$0` inside function.

---

In `fish`:

```
function tt
  printf '%s\n' "$_"
end
```

Comment: Consider updating the `zsh` answer with `${funcstack[@]:0:1}` which works whether array indexing starts at 0 (option `KSH_ARRAYS`) or 1 (default)

Answer (score 5):

In bash, you can use `${FUNCNAME[0]}`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function tt { echo ${FUNCNAME}; }
```

does it on my CentOS 6 box.