# Bash FUNCNAME equivalent in Dash

Tags: shell, function, dash

Bash can print the current function name:

```
$ bash -c 'g(){ echo $FUNCNAME; }; g'
g
```

However Dash cannot use *FUNCNAME*:

```
$ dash -c 'g(){ echo $FUNCNAME; }; g'
```

It is possible to access the current function name with Dash?

Comment: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.shells.dash/679

Comment: Related http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/261305/38906

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With any POSIX shells:

```
defun() {
  eval "
    $1() {
      FUNCNAME=$1
      $(cat)
    }
  "
}

defun g <<\}
  printf '%s\n' "$FUNCNAME"
}

g
```

Note that you can't call a function defined by `defun` inside body of a function defined by `defun`.

Comment: You could allow nesting by encoding the function call stack in the `FUNCNAME` variable, e.g. using `/` as a separator (I don't think any shell allows slashes in function names). It would be tricky to catch all return statements though, but you could make wrapper functions instead.

Comment: (but really, if you want ksh, you know where to find it!)

Comment: @Gilles: Good point. I'm on my holiday and don't have time to investigate more. If you don't mind, please making an improvement or providing your own answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and I have upvoted. However I will not accept because this is an awful workaround. It appears the answer is essentially "Dash cant do it"